# Html.CheckboxFor with clickable label not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to implement a checkbox that has a clickable label with the `Html.CheckboxFor` syntax. However, I am running into an issue where my checkbox is not allowing me to click it to toggle its state and is not being set properly when the page is loaded even thought the checked attribute is correct.

From what I have been reading, it seems that this is do to the extra hidden input field that gets generated to pass back false values to the controller on a form submittal. However, I still need to figure out a way around this and I feel like I am not the first one to be looking for a solution.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-check">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ProfilePublicViewable, new { @class = "form-check-input", @id = "val1", @value = "val1", @checked = "checked" })
    <label class="form-check-label" for="val1">Profile Public Viewable</label>
</div>
```

And here is what gets rendered to the DOM:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input checked="checked" class="form-check-input" id="val1" name="val1" type="checkbox" value="val1">
    <input name="ProfilePublicViewable" type="hidden" value="false">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="val1">Profile Public Viewable</label>
</div>
```

I have been looking around for examples on how to achieve this design, but seem to be coming up empty handed. Does anyone have any ideas as to where i am going wrong?

Comment: So you want it so when a user clicks on the label, the checkbox is checked?

Comment: @JamesS - essentially yes. For whatever reason, the checkbox state does not change no matter where I click. I am not sure if I have set something up incorrectly or what the problem may be.

Comment: so nothing changes the state of the checkbox?  not even checking the box itself?  Do you have something overlaying the checkbox with a higher z-index?

Comment: if nothing is overlaying the checkbox (per my previous comment), the next step would be for you to remove the css class `form-check-input` so you're dealing with raw HTML to see if that fixes it.  That's the only thing that's not shown here that could be causing a problem that I can see.

Comment: @BlairHolmes - Sure enough it was CSS related. Thank you for sending me down the right path. I have a class that uses icons instead of the default checkbox. Sure enough the actual checkbox was working (although I could have sworn this would not be the issue prior to posting my question) but my icons were not being targeted correctly. Thanks again!